# Multicast/Broadcast support on Android devices

Tags: android, udp, broadcast, multicast

I want to add UDP communication to my game to offer a multiplayer experience. Because I want to release my app, it's absolutely necessary that the UDP communication works constantly on all (or at least the majority of) devices (API Level 8+).

I primarily want to use MulticastSockets, but it seems that Multicast is not working correctly on a plurality of devices, and [there is no way to fix that](http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/).

So I have to find an alternative. One option might be to broadcast UDP communication.

Do targeted Android devices constantly support broadcasting? If not, which other options exist?